# How to add two numbers from event in a lamba function with node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to add to numbers together and put them in my dynamodb database , it works , but everytime i try it just put them side by side without adding them, exemple (50+50=5050 and not 100)

Here's what i tried

`"Total": { "S": event.First + event.Second }`

Comment: Convert them to integers first!? Apparently they are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I can see you save them as a String, do you wish to do so or would it be better as a number? I am also assuming that your numbers are coming into the event as Strings:

```
let num1 = parseInt(event.First);
let num2 = parseInt(event.Second);
let total = num1 + num2

let params = {
"pk": { "S": "123" },
"Total": { "N": total.toString() }
}
```

Comment: Like that? Sorry i'm new here.